# error: Listitem(String,String) is not public in Listitem; cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, android

I got the below error

> Error:(91, 37) error: Listitem(String,String) is not public in
>   Listitem; cannot be accessed from outside package

I have 2 packages

[image]

this is Listitem.java

```
public class Listitem implements Parcelable {
    String id;
    //String name;
    String url;

    Listitem(Parcel in){
        this.id = in.readString();
        //   this.name = in.readString();
        this.url = in.readString();
    }

    Listitem(String name, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(this.id);
        // dest.writeString(this.name);
        dest.writeString(this.url);

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Listitem> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Listitem>() {
        public Listitem createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Listitem(in);
        }

        public Listitem[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Listitem[size];
        }
    };
}
```

databasehandler

```
  List<Listitem> Objectslist = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        String selectQuery = "SELECT "+OBJECT_ID+" ,"+OBJECT_NAME+" ,"+OBJECT_URL +" FROM " + TABLE_OBJECTS;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Listitem object = new Listitem("1","b");
```

Why I am getting the error ? already Listitem is public , what I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the constructor like this:

```
Listitem(String name, String url) {
```

then they will get a package only visibility... So in order to make it accessible in other packages you need to make the constructor public too:

```
public Listitem(String name, String url) {
        this.id = id;
        this.url = url;
    }
```

Comment: oh i tried adding public to the parcelable  not the constructor thanks